# How to sign in on locale drone instance

Tags: drone.io, gogs

I'm running drone on my Synology NAS and can't find any hint what the password might be. I started with this [instruction](https://docs.drone.io/installation/gogs/single-machine/) and added `--env=DRONE_USER_CREATE=username:Imperative,admin:true`. In gogs personal access tokes, an entry `drone` is created. Also the logs state the admin account is being created:

> {"admin":true,"level":"info","login":"Imperative","machine":false,"msg":"bootstrap: account created","time":"2019-08-26T17:40:17Z","token":"*the_random_token*"}

I can access the web frontend login at the specified url, but i don't know what login to use. Neither my gogs login or gogs user + the drone token work.
The drone documentation is very rare on the topic.

Edit:
One more observation: when using some random login name, it says `Login Failed. Unauthorized`. When using my gogs credentials it says `Login Failed. Not Found`.